# Re-Create Bitmap Color table from 8 bpp bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc

I have a field device that uses the raster bytes from a bitmap to display an 8 Bit-per-pixel image. The device uses its own color table to display bitmaps which were created in MS Paint.

Given that the field device does not store the original color table, is it possible to download the image bytes, and recreate the bitmap in Windows? The bpp, height and width are all known, just the color table itself is missing. MS Paint seems to use the same color indexes for 256 bitmaps, so it seems that this should be possible.

I have a bitmap tools class, and I can create a 24-bit bitmap using the function shown below, and I am trying to modify this to also create 256 (8 bpp) bitmaps. What would it take to make this work?

```
// This function needs to be fixed.
// It only works for 24-BPP bitmaps.
void BitmapTools::SetHbitmap (BYTE* pBitmapBits, LONG lWidth,LONG lHeight, WORD wBitsPerPixel)
{
if (wBitsPerPixel < 24)
{
    MessageBox (GetFrame()->m_hWnd,
        "Error at BitmapTools::SetHbitmap(). This function only works with 24 BPP bitmaps.", 
        "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    return;
}

// Some basic bitmap parameters  
unsigned long headers_size = sizeof( BITMAPFILEHEADER ) +  
                             sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER );  
unsigned long pixel_data_size = lHeight * ( ( lWidth * ( wBitsPerPixel / 8 ) ) );  

BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = {0};  

// Set the size  
bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);  
// Bit count  
bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = wBitsPerPixel;  
// Use all colors  
bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
// Use as many colors according to bits per pixel
if (wBitsPerPixel < 24)
{
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = (1<<wBitsPerPixel);
}
else
{
     bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;  
}
// Store as un Compressed  
bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;  
// Set the height in pixels  
bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = lHeight;  
// Width of the Image in pixels  
bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = lWidth;  
// Default number of planes  
bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;  
// Calculate the image size in bytes  
bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = pixel_data_size;  
BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = {0};  
bfh.bfType = 0x4D42;    
// Offset to the RGBQUAD  
bfh.bfOffBits = headers_size;  
// Total size of image including size of headers  
bfh.bfSize = headers_size + pixel_data_size; 
HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);    
UINT usage;

// This does not work. Is there a way to add an arbitrary color
// table containing all 256 colors?
if (wBitsPerPixel < 24)
    {
        usage = DIB_PAL_COLORS;
    }
    else
    {
        usage = DIB_RGB_COLORS;
    }

//usage = DIB_RGB_COLORS;

    this->H_Bitmap = CreateDIBitmap (hdc, &bmpInfoHeader, CBM_INIT, pBitmapBits,(BITMAPINFO*)&bmpInfoHeader, usage);
}
```

Edit:  I made a new function based on someone else's post to create a 256 color bitmap, and I added the values from the color table used by MS Paint. It almost works, except the bottom-right of the image has a row of black pixels.  Here is the code I am now using:

Edit2: Thanks to everyone for your help, esp. Mark.  I got it working now. I made the corrections in the code below.

```
HBITMAP BitmapTools::Create8bppBitmap(HDC hdc, int width, int height, int paddedSize, LPVOID pBits)
{
BITMAPINFO *bmi = (BITMAPINFO *)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 256);
BITMAPINFOHEADER &bih(bmi->bmiHeader);
bih.biSize = sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bih.biWidth         = width;
bih.biHeight        = -height;
bih.biPlanes        = 1;
bih.biBitCount      = 8;
bih.biCompression   = BI_RGB;
bih.biSizeImage     = 0;
//bih.biXPelsPerMeter = 14173;
//bih.biYPelsPerMeter = 14173;
bih.biClrUsed       = 0;
bih.biClrImportant  = 0;

BYTE red[256] = {0, 128, 0, 128, 0, 128, 0, 192, 192, 166, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96,
    128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32,
    64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224,
    0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192,
    224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160,
    192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128,
    160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96,
    128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64,
    96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32,
    64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0,
    32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 255, 160,
    128, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255};

BYTE green[256] = {0, 0, 128, 128, 0, 0, 128, 192, 220, 202, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 160, 160, 160, 160,
    160, 160, 160, 160, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96,
    96, 96, 96, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 192, 192, 192,
    192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, 32, 32,
    32, 32, 32, 32, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128,
    128, 128, 128, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 224, 224,
    224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 160, 160, 160, 160,
    160, 160, 160, 160, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 251, 160, 128, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255};

BYTE blue[256] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 192, 192, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128,
    128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128,
    128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128,
    128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192,
    192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192,
    192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192, 192,
    192, 192, 192, 240, 164, 128, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255};

for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
{
    bmi->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = blue[i];
    bmi->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = green[i];
    bmi->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = red[i];          
    bmi->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = 0;
}

void *Pixels = NULL;
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBSection(hdc, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &Pixels, NULL, 0);
//HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBSection(hdc, bmi, DIB_PAL_COLORS, &Pixels, NULL, 0);


if(pBits != NULL)
{
    //fill the bitmap
    BYTE* pbBits = (BYTE*)pBits;
    BYTE *Pix = (BYTE *)Pixels;
    memcpy(Pix, pbBits, paddedSize); // --Correction made here--
}

free(bmi);

return hbmp;
```

}

I use this function to save the bitmap:

```
BOOL BitmapTools::SaveHBitmap(const char* filename, HBITMAP hbitmap)
{
BITMAP bitmap;
if (!GetObjectW(hbitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), (void*)&bitmap))
    return FALSE;

// Convert the color format to a count of bits.  
WORD clrbits = (WORD)(bitmap.bmPlanes * bitmap.bmBitsPixel);
if (clrbits == 1) clrbits = 1;
else if (clrbits <= 4)  clrbits = 4;
else if (clrbits <= 8)  clrbits = 8;
else if (clrbits <= 16) clrbits = 16;
else if (clrbits <= 24) clrbits = 24;
else clrbits = 32;

//clrUsed is zero for 24 bit and higher
int clrUsed = (clrbits <= 8) ? (1 << clrbits) : 0;
//TRACE("clrUsed %d\n", clrUsed);

int bitmapInfoSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * clrUsed;
PBITMAPINFO bitmapInfo = (PBITMAPINFO)new char[bitmapInfoSize];
memset(bitmapInfo, 0, bitmapInfoSize);

// Initialize the fields in the BITMAPINFO structure.  
bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth = bitmap.bmWidth;
bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight = bitmap.bmHeight;
bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biPlanes = bitmap.bmPlanes;
bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount = bitmap.bmBitsPixel;
bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = clrUsed;
bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

// Compute the number of bytes in the array of color
// indices and store the result in biSizeImage.  
// The width must be DWORD aligned unless the bitmap
// is RLE compressed. 
int dibSize = ((bitmap.bmWidth * clrbits + 31) & ~31) / 8 * bitmap.bmHeight;
char* dib = new char[dibSize];

bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = dibSize;

// Set biClrImportant to 0, indicating that all of
// the device colors are important.  
bitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

//bitmapInfo->bmiColors [0].rgbBlue

PBITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER)bitmapInfo;

HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);

if (!GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, bmpInfoHeader->biHeight, dib, bitmapInfo, 0))
{
    delete bitmapInfo;
    delete[]dib;
    return FALSE;
}

DWORD dwTmp;
BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader;
bmpFileHeader.bfType = 0x4d42; // 0x42 = "B" 0x4d = "M"
bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + clrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
bmpFileHeader.bfSize = bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits + dibSize;
HANDLE hfile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    WriteFile(hfile,(LPVOID)&bmpFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), (LPDWORD) &dwTmp, NULL);
    WriteFile(hfile, (void*)bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + clrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD), (LPDWORD) &dwTmp, NULL);
    WriteFile(hfile, (void*)dib, dibSize, (LPDWORD) &dwTmp, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hfile);
}

DeleteDC(hdc);
delete bitmapInfo;
delete[]dib;

return TRUE;
```

}

Here is the image I get. Note the last row has a set of black pixels.  I'm not 100% sure that the problem is with these functions (my next step will be to compare the bytes from the original bitmap to the ones from the field device).
[image]

Edit:  I checked the bytes from the field device, and they match the original bitmap raster bytes 100%, so I believe the problem is in one of these functions.

Comment: Well you need the color table to recreate the colors.

Comment: You can take one of the saved images from MS Paint and copy the color table from that.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Are all the color tables the same for any 256-bit image?  For example, It seems that the color 'red' always is 01001111, (79 decimal), from MS Paint, regardless of how many colors, or image size.

Comment: The color table for 256-color bitmaps is user-defined. Any image authoring program can store an arbitrarily chosen set of colors. If it were fixed, why waste previous space in the image file?

Comment: Thanks. I get that the table is user-defined, but it seems to me that Microsoft paint always uses the same table for specific colors in all 256-color bitmaps. Say I have a 256-color bitmap that has only one color, red. If I make another one that has 200 colors, and a different size, why does a 'red' pixel have the same index in both bitmaps? Is there a default color table that ms paint uses?

Comment: I just checked the color tables in 2 different 256-color bitmaps in MS paint, and they both have exactly the same values. It seems that Microsoft Paint simply uses the same table, regardless of size or colors used. It looks like I can use a color table from one of the images, and use it for all of them.

Comment: Show what your bitmap is supposed to look like, and what it looks like when you attempt to paint it (if it's a big image then just show the top-left corner of the image) Also try forcing `usage = DIB_RGB_COLORS;` for palette images.

Comment: will do. I will edit my post.

Comment: When you do the `memcpy`, you're not adjusting `width` to a multiple of 4 bytes, could that be the problem?

Comment: That's it! I did not account for the padding.  I added a parameter to the function that saves to the hBitmap for the correct size, and it works perfectly now.  Thanks Mark. I will post corrected code.

Comment: Glad I could help.